# Changing the Imageview background  if bluetooth is off

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I need to change the background image of an Imageview if bluetooth is off

I have an Imageview and on clicking that if bluetooth is on i am setting one image and on second click I should make the bluetooth off and the background of imageview should be changed

I tried a lot but its not changing on second click

Here is my code

```
            bluetoothimg.setOnClickListener(new View. OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(!mBtAdapter.isEnabled()){
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
            final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings");  
            intent.setComponent(cn);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            bluetoothimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt);
            startActivityForResult( intent,  REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            //BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
            mBtAdapter.enable();

            }
            else {

                bluetoothimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_grey);
                //BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                mBtAdapter.disable();


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Snippet will work

```
bluetoothimg.setOnClickListener(new View. OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

      if(bluetoothimg.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("off")) //Bluetooth Disabled
      {

        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

      }
      else   //Disable Bluetooth
      {

                if(mBtAdapter.disable())
                {
                  bluetoothImg.setTag("off");
                  bluetoothimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_gray); 
                } 

       }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(resultCode=RESULT_OK)
                {
                   bluetoothImg.setTag("on");
                   bluetoothimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt); 
                }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,here inside onActivityResult means?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for questioning once again, I want to know about bluetoothimg.getTag()==0 , bluetoothImg.setTag(0);    bluetoothImg.setTag(1);

Comment: setTag helps you to identify current state of image.I am setting image tag to 0 when disabling bluetooth and setting its tag to 1 while enabling bluetooth.

Comment: showing  Incompatible operand types Object and int  on this line if(bluetoothimg.getTag()==0)

Comment: See updated code now.Now setting tag in string format.Its working at my end

Comment: SORRY,  Still its showing cannot convert from int to boolean at this line  if(resultCode=RESULT_OK)       and  The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) is undefined for the type Object at this line super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: I added the complete code at the end of my question on which its showing above  errors, could u pls tell where i am wrong